# Fuzzy search of users to retrieve associated data

Tags: python, redis, sparql

I am building an application which identifies **people mentioned in free text (order of magnitude of a million)** and stores their names as keys with one or more (for handling people with the same name) **associated URIs** pointing to a **SPARQL based knowledge graph node** which then lets me retrieve additional data about them.

Currently I am storing the name and last name as keys in a **Redis DB** but the problem is that I need to use **fuzzy search** on those names using the Rapidfuzz library **https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz** because Redis only provides a simple LD distance fuzzy query which is not enough.

What architecture would you recommend? Happy 2023!!!

Comment: Could you maybe fit the million keys in memory, get the fuzzy search result candidates, and then look up in redis?

Comment: Hi @Yati thanks for chiming in. The simple way is to have the million keys in memory say in a python dict as you say, use rapidfuzz to retrieve candidates and have the corresponding URIs to the SPARQL backend, but I am afraid this approach is not too scalable/robust.

Comment: Did you consider using the redis module RediSearch?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Guy RediSearch looks very interesting for many of its other features, but for fuzzy search it only seems to support LD and not a lot of the more complex similarity metrics supported by RapidFuzz (or FuzzyWuzzy)